# HttpErrorResponse : ionic 3 & dialogflow

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, http-headers, ionic3, dialogflow-es

I'm using dialog flow in ionic 3.I'm trying to send and get response through http request. This is my home.ts file code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Message } from '../module/message.module';
import { ChatProvider } from '../../providers/chat/chat';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  messages: Message[] = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private chatprovider: ChatProvider) {

  }

  // ionViewDidLoad(){
  //   let message = new Message("hi")
  //   this.messages.push(message);
  // }

  sendMesage(message_content) {
    this.chatprovider.sendMessage(message_content.value).subscribe(res =>{
      console.log(res);
      // let message = new Message(res.result.speech);
      // this.messages.push(message);
      // message_content.value = '';
    }, err => {
      console.log(err)
    }
    )
  }
}
```

this is my chatprovider.ts file code

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ChatProvider {

  url = 'https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query';
  accessToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello ChatProvider Provider');
  }

  sendMessage(message: string) {
    let data = {
      lang: "en",
      query: message
    }
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append("Authorization","Bearer" + this.accessToken);
    return this.http.post(this.url, data,{headers: headers})
          .map(res => {
            return res
          })
  }

}
```

This is the error I'm facing

> polyfills.js:3 POST https://api.dialogflow.com/v1/query 403 () s @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 onScheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleTask @
>   polyfills.js:3 r.scheduleMacroTask @ polyfills.js:3 (anonymous) @
>   polyfills.js:3 o.(anonymous function) @ polyfills.js:2 (anonymous) @
>   http.js:2364 Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
>   Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160 subscribeToResult @
>   subscribeToResult.js:23 MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:132
>   MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:129 MergeMapSubscriber._next
>   @ mergeMap.js:112 Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:93
>   ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:49
>   Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172 Observable.subscribe @
>   Observable.js:160 MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:87
>   Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157 FilterOperator.call @
>   filter.js:60 Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157 MapOperator.call
>   @ map.js:56 Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157 MapOperator.call
>   @ map.js:56 Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
>   webpackJsonp.197.HomePage.sendMesage @ home.ts:23 (anonymous) @
>   HomePage.html:24 handleEvent @ core.js:13589 callWithDebugContext @
>   core.js:15098 debugHandleEvent @ core.js:14685 dispatchEvent @
>   core.js:10004 (anonymous) @ core.js:10629 (anonymous) @
>   platform-browser.js:2628 t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3 onInvokeTask @
>   core.js:4751 t.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3 r.runTask @ polyfills.js:3
>   e.invokeTask @ polyfills.js:3 p @ polyfills.js:2 v @ polyfills.js:2
>   home.ts:29

Comment: Error says that, you are not authorized to access the resource. Its forbidden.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the valid token?

Comment: yes, I've just copy-pasted the developer token form the dialog flow website.